# Tensorflow freezes when not using a supervisor

Tags: python, tensorflow

**No GPU, no queues, Tensorflow 1.1.0**

There's this sample LSTM code:

https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/rnn/ptb/ptb_word_lm.py

This code works. It prints training process info, it's cool. Now, I tried to write a trained model graph to disk using `freeze_graph()`, and eventually I found out that this LSTM tutorial uses a `Supervisor` to train the model, and `Supervisor` freezes the graph, and a frozen graph can not be used in the `freeze_graph()` procedure.

I tried to switch from a `Supervisor` to using an ordinary session. The **only** changes made were in the `main()` procedure (apart from importing some stuff). It now looks like this (changed parts are highlighted, and I removed all graph-saving related stuff, it's not the matter here):

```
with tf.Graph().as_default():
        initializer = tf.random_uniform_initializer(
            -config.init_scale, config.init_scale)
        with tf.name_scope("Train"):
            train_input = PTBInput(
                config=config, data=train_data, name="TrainInput")
            with tf.variable_scope("Model", reuse=None, initializer=initializer):
                m = PTBModel(
                    is_training=True, config=config, input_=train_input)
            tf.summary.scalar("Training Loss", m.cost)
            tf.summary.scalar("Learning Rate", m.lr)
        with session.Session() as sess:  # CHANGED
            sess.run(variables.global_variables_initializer())  # CHANGED
            for i in range(config.max_max_epoch):
                lr_decay = config.lr_decay ** max(i +
                                                  1 - config.max_epoch, 0.0)
                m.assign_lr(sess, config.learning_rate * lr_decay)
                print("Epoch: %d Learning rate: %.3f" %
                      (i + 1, sess.run(m.lr)))
                train_perplexity = run_epoch(sess, m, eval_op=m.train_op,
                                             verbose=True)
                print("Epoch: %d Train Perplexity: %.3f" %
                      (i + 1, train_perplexity))
```

After these changes the whole thing started to freeze at this very line:

https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/rnn/ptb/ptb_word_lm.py#L300

It is a `session.run()` call in model internals (doesn't react to Ctrl+C, killable with `kill -9`):

```
vals = session.run(fetches, feed_dict)
```

Previous `session.run()` calls (there's some) worked just fine.

What did I do wrong? It seems like all variables are initialized just fine (which was done by `Supervisor` in the original code). Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use [`tf.train.Supervisor`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Supervisor), the framework code automatically calls [`tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess)`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/start_queue_runners) (along with initializing variables) at the beginning of the session. If you switch back to using a raw [`tf.Session`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Session), you must call this manually to start the input pipeline. A change like the following should work:

```
# ...
with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
  tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess)
  # ...
```